# Angularjs select option removal with ng-if bug

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue that when I remove an option and try to hide the select in case the select is empty that bugs out.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/de564uew/)

Notice that when you remove x and then y everything is fine.

However, when you **first pick y it pops up a blank option in your select** for some unknown reason.

And the even more odd thing is, when you remove the `ng-if="permissionSelect"` from the div, that bug does not occur!!!

What am I missing? is this a bug? is this suppose to happen?

**EDIT1:**
Using `ng-show` solves this, I still wanna know wtf happened though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. It's related to the fact that `ngIf` directive creates new scope which inherits from the base scope. Since you are using primitive property for the model `permissionsSelect` it looses connection with initial scope list. You can fix it by using object reference:

```
$scope.permissionsList = [{name:'x'},{name:'y'}];

$scope.permissions = {};
$scope.permissions.select = $scope.permissionsList[0]; // Initial default value for the select

$scope.removeOption = function(option) {
    var index = $scope.permissionsList.indexOf(option);
    $scope.permissionsList.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.permissions.select = $scope.permissionsList[0]; 
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/de564uew/3/

This is abstract from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf):

> Note that when an element is removed using ngIf its scope is destroyed and a new scope is created when the element is restored. The scope created within ngIf inherits from its parent scope using prototypal inheritance. An important implication of this is if ngModel is used within ngIf to bind to a javascript primitive defined in the parent scope. In this case any modifications made to the variable within the child scope will override (hide) the value in the parent scope.

Comment: So why is it working properly from the first option that was defined at the begining?

Also, why the blank option?? Notice that you can still remove it and it will work properly but it just reference it somehow and adds a blank option for some reason.

You can also notice that AFTER you choose an option with that blank option, it will remove the blank option.

Comment: I'm honestly puzzled about this too. It is related to `ngIf` scopes and how it applies cloned elements. But all together - pretty complex machinery, which I still can't realized in this case.

Comment: It explains why it works with `ngShow`: because `ngShow` doesn't clone elements and simply show/hide them. So there is no transclusions and scope shenanigans.